# What's the effect on a second request of calling Thread.currentThread().sleep(2000) in a Spring MVC request handler?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-mvc, concurrency, thread-sleep

I need to wait for a condition in a Spring MVC request handler while I call a third party service to update some entities for a user.

The wait averages about 2 seconds.

I'm calling `Thread.sleep` to allow the remote call to complete and for the entities to be updated in the database:

```
Thread.currentThread().sleep(2000);
```

After this, I retrieve the updated models from the database and display the view.

**However, what will be the effect on parallel requests that arrive for processing at this controller/request handler?**

Will parallel requests also experience a wait?

Or will they be spawned off into separate threads and so not be affected by the delay experienced by the current request?

Comment: Why don't you display some sort of "progress" indicator and come back in 2 seconds instead of putting the thread to sleep? It's a much better approach for an MVC architecture.

Comment: Yes, that's a good idea. But because the view needs to be passed various model entities, I would first need to render the view with some progress message - and then re-render it with the updated entities after the third party remote call completes. I'm just not sure how to do this. Are you talking about using JSON or something? The only simple way I can think of to do this is a HTML META tag refresh on the JSP and then a redirect back to the original request handler and re-rendering of the view.

Comment: You said that the models are retrieved from the database, so call your remote service and let it fill up your database, then come back in 2 seconds and try to retrieve the data. In the mean time display a "progress" view so the user doesn't think your app is broken.

Comment: What I was asking was how you propose specifically to "come back" later: JSON? A redirect back to the handler & re-render the page? some other option?

Comment: probably re-direct would be easier... I'm not sure how you would do it in Spring, but if you ask around you would get a quick answer I suppose.

Comment: `Thread.currentThread().sleep(2000);` should be written as `Thread.sleep(2000);` since `sleep` is a static method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are doing may work sometimes, but it is not a reliable solution.

The Java Future interface, along with a configured ExecutorService allows you to begin some operation and have one or more threads wait until the result is ready (or optionally until a certain amount of time has passed).

You can find documentation for it here:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html

Comment: Looks complex. So this basically creates a background task and when it completes I can have it trigger some action. As you said, my approach is not "reliable" because the remote service may not respond in a particular timeframe. I wonder if a JavaScript timer and simple ajax call from the page might be a simpler way to check on the updated status.

Comment: Well, I may be misreading what you are trying to do or the limits you are working with.  For some reason I was assuming that you would eventually know if your update has succeeded.  A benefit of Futures for that sort of thing is that if your update happens in less than the 2 second interval and the Future thread can determine that, you can return a response more quickly to the user.

Comment: Well, I could call `Thread.sleep()` in a loop every 100 milliseconds - in which case there would be very little usability difference between your implementation and mine. Perhaps yours would be more "ideal" but they would both "work". But my question is really more about the effect of calling `Thread.sleep()` on other parallel requests. `Future` is good to know about though. Thanks for the link.

Comment: The effect of sleep on other threads should be (in a decent operating system and Java implementation) very little.  A sleeping thread will allow other active threads to run a bit more.  It will consume some memory until it terminates, so e.g. if you ran a large number of threads and make them sleep, you might run have problems with that.